# change onclick function from a href to div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change this script which was posted here so that I can scrap my rubbish attempt at jQuery, but I need the script to react to clicks on a div id or class rather than on an href link

UPDATED WITH ALL CODE AS USING .class or #id doesn't work

```
<div class="top_menu_menub">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="sub">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Control Center</a></li>
            <li><a href="">APEC Trinity</a></li>
            <li><a href="">APEC Living</a></li>
            <li><a href="">APEC Energy</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.menu_button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var ulId = $this.attr("href");
            var clicked_menu_is_visible = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId).filter(':visible').length > 0;
            var visible_uls = $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible');
            if (visible_uls.length === 0) { //no menus showing - just show clicked menu 
                $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                $ul.slideToggle('medium');
            } else { //close open menus (should only be one open) then open clicked menu
            //via callback 
            $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible').slideUp("medium", function() {
                $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                //open clicked menu - unless menu was already open when clicked
                if (!clicked_menu_is_visible) {
                    $ul.slideToggle('medium');
                }
            });
        }  
    });
 });
 });

.top_menu_menub {
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
    background-image: url(../images/apecbuttona.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 8px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;}
#menu {list-style-type:none; width:200px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; height: 24px;}
#menu ul {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; border: solid 1px #eee; border-radius: 5px; }
#menu li {float:left; margin:1px 1px 0 0;position:relative; z-index: 9999}
#menu li.sub {width: 200px; height: 16px; padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;}
#menu li.sub:hover { color:#00CCFF; background-image: url(../images/apecbutton.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 8px 0px; height: 24px;}
#menu li a {display:block; color:#999; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:23px; width:107px; text-decoration:none; text-align:left; cursor:pointer; font-weight:100; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; padding-left: 8px;}
#menu li a:hover {background:#fff; color:#4FA4F9;}
#menu ul {position:absolute;left:-9800px;width:115px; }
#menu li.click {}
#menu li.click ul{left: 12px; top:22px; background: #fff; } /* the background image is for IE7 */
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't changing the selector for your click event work? Something like `$('a.menu_button').click(...` to `$('#div_id').click(...`.

Comment: need to provide some html or all you get is some blind guessing code

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
$(function() {
 $('.classname').click(function() {
...
```

(assuming your classname is defined in a referenced css file)

or

```
$(function() {
 $('#idname').click(function() {
...
```

and it will do what you are wanting.

Comment: then there is something wrong in my code as i did try that: thanks for replying... Updated with more info... using hover to swap an image in css divs could that be causing a conflict?